# How to handle exception in event handlers?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, event-handling

I have small piece of code which is part of wcf service-client. At client side i am checking

```
serviceClient.open()
```

Is throwing any exception ? if it is throwing I am handling it (**`FaultException,EndpointNotFoundException`**)
so that my client will loop through until host is up.

When coming to actual problem.I am calling server method in an event handler . If due to some reason host goes down I need to handle exception there. But i read like handling exception in event handler  is not good practice.
what is replacement for that.here is my sample.

```
myTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { Message(); };

private void Message(){
    try {
        serviceClient.Get(message, content);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException) {
        while (Client.IsConnectionUp()==false)  {
            Console.WriteLine("CommunicationException....");
            if (serviceClient.State != CommunicationState.Opened) {
                Client.IsConnectionUp();
            }
        }
    } catch(ObjectDisposedException) {
        while (Client.IsConnectionUp() == false) {
            Console.WriteLine("ObjectDisposedException....");
            Client.IsConnectionUp();
        }
    } 
}
```

here is `IsConnectionUp()` method

```
IsConnectionUp() {
    serviceClient= new serviceClient(); 
    try {
        serviceClient.Open();
        return true;
    } catch (FaultException) {
        if (serviceClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) {
            Console.WriteLine("FaultException");
            serviceClient= new serviceClient();
        }
        return false;
    } catch (EndpointNotFoundException) {
        Console.WriteLine("EndpointNotFoundException...");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please give some suggestion.